# Unable to run webdriver test in chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to run my webdriver test on chrome browser but I am getting the following error.

This is my java code

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class class8q6spaqx9q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver wd = null;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");
        wd  = new ChromeDriver();

        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wd.get("http://www.google.com/");
    } 
}
```

Following is the error I get

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Created new window in existing browser session.
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: '*****-personal', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.8.0-35-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at class8q6spaqx9q3.main(class8q6spaqx9q3.java:28)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: '*****-personal', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.8.0-35-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:7235/status] to be available after 20002 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download ChromeDriver from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). Put it into home directory. And set the path to it.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/chromedriver");
```